# Skrollr.js not activating

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, skrollr

I have spent the past 3 hours trying to get skrollr to show me anything! I have tried calling the script before the body, in the header, and have tried a whole bunch of tutorials to try to get it it to work but i'm not sure why it's not working AT ALL.

In the `<head>` I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/go-skrollr.js"></script>
```

Ok as per @melc I made some changes, the one below being the main one. Still with no luck.

```
(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){skrollr.init();});
})();
```

And in my summary row (div right below nav) I have

```
<div class="container" data-center="opacity: 1" data-200-top="opacity: 0" data-anchor-target="#summary h3">
```

To my knowledge this should make the content inside that container disappear when the h3 is 200 pixels from the top.

I have tried calling it a bunch of different ways, still with no luck!

[Live site](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/)

Comment: there is no element matching this selector `#summary h3` but there is for `.summary h3`

Comment: @melc gave that a shot, did not work unfortunately, any other ideas?

Comment: it is also required to call `skrollr.init();` please check out the documentation here https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#lets-get-serious

Comment: @melc yes I have that in my go-skrollr.js file

Comment: this should be called when the document has been loaded eg on `$(document).ready(function(){skrollr.init();});`

Comment: @melc gave that a shot, no luck, i updated the live site if you would like to take a look.

Comment: Great but also update the `summary h3` part to `.summary h3`. Also need to correct code in `go-skrollr.js` see the console. You'll have to wrap in an anonymous function as you had it

Comment: @melc ok i gave that a shot (i'm pretty sure its correct) but im still getting the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point there are three issues, that if are corrected you will see `Skrollr.js` in action *(this has been tested on the site given in the OP and it works)*.

**issue 1** - The `data-anchor-target="#summary h3"` must be modified to `data-anchor-target=".summary h3"`

**issue 2** - The `.hero` element must not have `height:100%` , just comment it out, because it reaches 6k pixels in height after the initialization of `skrollr` for some reason, which can be examined later on.

**issue 3** - Proper initialization of `skrollr` must take place. Right now at the console the message `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` is displayed and it is referred to `go-skrollr.js` file. This is because `jQuery` library file must be included before referencing `skrollr.js` library file.

Comment: you're awesome that totally did the trick! Do you happen to have a workaround for the `height:100%` by any chance? Great work dude!! Definitely learned a couple of things

Comment: @Dimitrov thanks i'm glad it helped. Regarding `height:100%` i suggest  to remove it,  after all it is not used in the corresponding `hero` or `jumbotron` elements of the bootstrap examples and actually i think it is not of much use to have it there.

Comment: I managed to figure it out I just had to change the `forceHeight` option to `false` in go-skrollr.js thanks again dude!!!

Comment: "This is because jQuery library file must be included before referencing skrollr.js library file.". No. You don't need jQuery at all.

Comment: @Prinzhorn if i remember correctly it was required at the specific point of code since the OP was calling `$(document).ready` without having included `jQuery`

Comment: Sure, but that was skrollr unrelated.

Comment: @Prinzhorn yes, the answer was only related to specifying and resolving the issues of the site at that point of time in order to make things work as requested by the OP. However please feel free to supplement/modify the answer to make it more accurate or simply provide more info. Nice library by the way!